# Why is my output wrong in this recursive function?

Tags: c, function, recursion

The function needs to return the minimum pass from number x to number y using (1+) or (2*) only. for example, from 8 to 19, the min pass is "3" 
 because (8*2+1+1+1=19), now my code is outputting a different number instead of 3, what is my problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f(int x, int y){

  if(x==y) 
    return 0;
  if(x>y)
    return -1;
  if(2*x < y){
    int max=f(2*x, y);
    return max+1;
  }
  else if(x+1<y){
    int max=f(x+1,y);
    return max+1;
  }
}

int main()
  {
    int idx=f(8,19);
    printf("%d", idx);

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: this looks like a job for a debugger!

Comment: It prints 22 when I run it. Please make sure you've posted the correct [MCVE].

Comment: at first glance it looks ok. But I am not a compiler to compile it, nor a SO to run it, nor a debugger to debug it. You need to debug your own code.

Comment: @jwdonahue I edited my question, n,p 0 or 22 the problem is that it need to output 3....

Comment: Have you stepped through it in a debugger yet?

Comment: Please enable all compiler warnings such as *warning C4715: 'f': not all control paths return a value*

Comment: When x = 18, none of the if-tests becomes true

Comment: What if `x` and/or `y` are negative?

Comment: I solved it just for positive numbers

Comment: @sam0101 then you should use unsigned int, not signed int.

Comment: @jwdonahue Yes you are correct, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here.

*1. When `x` becomes 1 less than `y` non of the if condition will be met and you will not return anything which is undefined behavior.*

*Hence replace*

```
else if(x+1<y){
```

*with*

```
else {
```

*2. You should not add `1+max` in case of `if(2*x < y)` to get the correct result since you want to count only number of  `+1` done.*

*hence change*

`int max=f(2*x, y);
     return max+1;`

*To*

`int max=f(2*x, y);
     return max;`

After adding all your code becomes.

```
int f(int x, int y){

  if(x==y)
    return 0;
  if(x>y)
    return -1;
  if(2*x < y){
    int max=f(2*x, y);
    return max;
  }
  else {
    int max=f(x+1,y);
    return max+1;
  }
}
```

Comment: warning C4715: 'f': not all control paths return a value

Comment: Put the `return -1` at the end of the function and drop the `if(x>y)`.

Comment: @jwdonahue Yes did! Thank you.

Comment: @jwdonahue I think no need of `return -1` at the end.

Comment: My compiler says your code doesn't return a value on all paths. Placing the `return -1' at the end, is the catch-all "we got here, something is very wrong statement".  That would also include the `x>y` scenario.

Comment: @jwdonahue I'm using `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4`  but not getting any warnings after I drop out `if(x+1<y)` since that condition is unnecessary .

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should think in your mind how your function would work with its variables. When it gets the last iteration:

```
...
else if( x+1 < y ) {
    int max = f( x+1, y );
    return x+1;
}
...
```

Kiran here is right. With x = 8 and y = 19 (as you mentioned above) you'll recall the function with x = 18 that'll return undefined because no one of your if will be matched.

A possible solution could be:

```
int f( int x, int y ) {

    if( x < y ) {

        if( x * 2 < y ) return f( x * 2, y );
        else if( x + 1 <= y ) return 1 + f( x + 1, y );

    } else if( x == y ) return 0;
    else return -1;

}
```

Comment: I like it! The least likely corner cases are handled last and all control flow paths return something meaningful. I think x and y should be unsigned. Either way, a check should be added for 2*x overflow.